# Creating a function that translates number to letter

Tags: python

I have written this function which is supposed to go through a user-provided string like `1-3-5`, and output a corresponding series of letters, where A is assigned to 1, B is assigned to 2, C is assigned to 3, etc. So in the case of `1-3-5` the output would be `ACE`. For `2-3-4`, it should print `BCD`. For `?-3-4` or `--3-4` it should still print `BCD.` Here is the code I have written so far:

```
def number_to_letter(encoded):
    result = ""
    start = 0
    for char in range(len(encoded)):
        if encoded[char] == '-':
            i = encoded.index("-")
            sub_str = encoded[start:i]
            if not sub_str.isdigit():
                result += ""
            else:
                letter = chr(64 + int(sub_str))
                if 0 < int(sub_str) < 27:
                    result += letter

                else:
                    result += ""

            start += len(sub_str) + 1
    return result

print(num_to_let('4-3-25'))
```

My output is `D`, when it should be `DCY`. I am trying to do this without using any lists or using the `split` function, just by finding the `-` character in the sub-string and converting the numbers before it into a letter. What can I do?

Comment: Use `encoded.split('-')` instead of reading character by character.

Comment: I am sorry I should have specified; I need to do this without split function. I have updated the original post to reflect this.

Comment: I would suggest not using `str` as a variable name.  `str` is a very basic builtin which you may very well need to use, but won't be able to if you've locally redefined it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I added `print(number_to_letter('1-3-5'))` and confirmed that it doesn't print anything.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing something like this:

```
def number_to_letter(encoded):
    result  = ""
    buffer = ""
    for ch in encoded:
        if ch == '-':
            if buffer and 0 < int(buffer) < 27:
                result += chr(64 + int(buffer))
            buffer = ""
        elif ch.isdigit():
            buffer += ch
    else:
        if buffer and 0 < int(buffer) < 27:
            result += chr(64 + int(buffer))
        return result 

print(number_to_letter('1-3-5'))
```

**output:**

```
ACE
```

**Explanation:**

we loop for each character and add it to some buffer. when we encounter `-` (delimiter) we try to parse the buffer and reset it. And we do the same parsing at the end one more time and return the result.

The way the validation works is that, whenever we populate the buffer we check for number validity (using `.isdigit()`) and when we parse the buffer we check for the range constraints.

Comment: This is very helpful -- thank you kindly! In my original program, I had accounted for non-numeric input or numbers that were less than 0 or greater than 26. Would I be able to do the same in the code you have provided?

Comment: @AnthonyPetruzzio There you go! :)

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what purpose buffer serves or why int(buffer) works. Isn't buffer a string? Would you mind explaining that in a little more detail?

Comment: @AnthonyPetruzzio sure. since we are operating with for-loop (char-by-char), we need some temporary scratch space we could accumulate the characters at.

Comment: and when ever we encounter the `'-'`, we try to parse the data we have accumulated over there => add to the result => and finally reset that variable

Comment: How can you do int(buffer)? Wouldn't this just be int() of an empty string? How does that not produce an error?

Comment: Why would buffer be empty? We are not running `int` at the beginning but rather after having buffer been populated (note the `buffer += ch` statement). Anyway, I would suggest you to put some breakpoints and try running it inside debugger(available in vscode/pycharm) to see how exactly it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
combination = "1-2-3"

def seperate(s, sep='-'):
    return [s[:s.index(sep)]] + seperate(s[s.index(sep)+1:]) if sep in s else [s]

combination = seperate(combination)

print("".join([alphabet[int(i)-1] for i in combination]))
```

Comment: He's edited the question to say he doesn't want to use `split()`

Comment: oh god... *why*

Answer (score 0):

I see you don't want to use `split`, how about `filter`? ;)

```py
import itertools

s = '1-2-3'
values = [''.join(e) for e in filter(
     lambda l: l != ['-'],
     [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(
         [*s], lambda s: s.isnumeric()
        )
      ]
    )
]
```

That will essentially do what `.split('-')` does on `s`. Also `list(s)` will behave the same as `[*s]` if you wanna use that instead.

Now you can just use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) and [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) to construct the string you require-

```py
start_pivot = ord('A') - 1
res = ''.join([chr(int(i) + start_pivot) for i in values])
```

#### Output

```py
>>> s = '2-3-4'
>>> values = [''.join(e) for e in filter(
...:      lambda l: l != ['-'],
...:      [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(
...:          [*s], lambda s: s.isnumeric()
...:         )
...:       ]
...:     )
...: ]
>>> start_pivot = ord('A') - 1
>>> res = ''.join([chr(int(i) + start_pivot) for i in values])
>>> res
'BCD'
```

Comment: This solution doesn't allow 2-digit numbers, e.g. `12-3` should produce `LC`

Comment: @Barmar oh I didn't notice that, should be fixed now

Comment: "I am trying to do this without using any lists or ..."

Answer (score 0):

the approach of this code is to find the first '-' and then store where it is so next time we can look for the first '-' after the last one

when the comments in my code talk about a cycle means going through the loop (While looping:) once

```py
def number_to_letter(encoded):
    letterString = ""
    startSubStr = 0
    endSubStr = 0
    looping = True

    while looping:
        if endSubStr > (len(encoded)-4):# if we're at the last number we don't look for '-'. we go to the end of the str and end the loop
            endSubStr = len(encoded)
            looping = False
        else:
            endSubStr = encoded.index('-', startSubStr) #find the first '-' after the '-' found in the last cycle

        number = int(encoded[startSubStr:endSubStr]) #get the number between the '-' found in the last cycle through this loop and the '-' found in this one
        if number < 27:
            letter = chr(64 + int(number))
            letterString += letter

        startSubStr = endSubStr + 1 #set the start of the substring to the end so the index function doesn't find the '-' found in this cycle again 

    return letterString

print(number_to_letter("23-1-1-2")) #>>> WAAB
```

result:
WAAB

Comment: Can I ask why you chose to subtract 4 in the first if statement?

Comment: to check if I'm approaching the end of the string if so, an error would occur if I try to find the next '-' because there is no '-' at the end of the string. endSubStr now get set to the actual end of the string

Comment: @Jorrit200 While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @DevCl9 thank you for your feedback. I will add some comments to my code in the near future. and a general description to this awnser.

Answer (score 0):

No lists, okay. But what about dicts?

```
def abc(nums):
    d = {'-':'','1':'A','2':'B','3':'C','4':'D','5':'E','6':'F','7':'G','8':'H','9':'I','0':'J'}
    res = ''
    for n in nums: res += d[n]
    return res
    
print(abc('1-2-3-9-0')) # Output: ABCIJ
```

Here is a corrected version:

```
def abc(nums):
    d = {'-':'','1':'A','2':'B','3':'C','4':'D','5':'E','6':'F','7':'G','8':'H','9':'I','0':'J'}
    res = ''
    for n in nums:
        if n in d:
            res += d[n]
    return res

print(abc('?-2-3-9-0')) # Output: BCIJ
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use dicts.

Comment: this just straight-up crushes with `KeyError` for `abc('?-2-3-9-0')`

Comment: This solution was given before the author add the new idea about '?-3-4'. And before he restrict to use dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

No lists, no dicts. What about RegExp?

```
import re

def get_letter(n):
    if int(n) in range(1,27): return chr(int(n)+64)

def number_to_letter(s):
    return re.sub(r'\d+', lambda x: get_letter(x.group()), s).replace('-','')

print(number_to_letter('1-2-26')) # Output: ABZ
```

Comment: @Yuri Khristich your solution doesn't for the non-numerical chars (in-fact quite inconsistent about it) . try " ?-3-4 or --3-4 it should still print BCD"  (double sic!)! by-the-way why are you using `range`? isn't that an iterable?

Comment: I think we don't need to take this problem too serious. The author obviously has very vague idea about what he's doing. My solution ignores these '?-3-4', '--3-4' etc. Your solution trows error and falls. As for the `range`, what do you mean? It just checks if `n` (the given number) belongs to the range from 1 to 26, or if it less than 26 and larger that 0. It can be replaced with this `0 < n < 27` as well.